# express cannot GET error using with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I manage to setup react, basically express just as the api server. I can navigate around my react app using react-router, it's a single page application.

But when I refresh for example http://localhost/login I got error of cannot GET /login I know the issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't posted your code, but I guess that you don't return the React app at the `*` route, which means that if you start at `/`, you'll be fine because it's handled, but if you want to get any other endpoint not via the app itself, but directly via an address, Express will look for a `/login` (for example) route handler and hence it's not there, it'll return 404.

TLDR: send the React SPA as the response on `* GET` and React Router will handle the rest.